# Sqlite: append a new element to an existing array

Tags: json, sqlite, sqlite-json1

From the sqlite3 doc

```sql
select json_insert('{"a":2,"c":4}', '$.e', 99) -- → '{"a":2,"c":4,"e":99}'
```

But how to append a new element to an array?

```sql
select json_insert('[1,2,3]', ??, 4) -- → '[1, 2, 3, 4]'
update someTable set someArray = json_insert(someArray, ??, 'some new value')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a few trials, I finally figured out

```sql
update some_table
  set some_array = json_insert(
    some_array,
    '$[' || json_array_length(some_array) || ']',
    'new item'
  )
  where id = some_id;
```

Comment: Appending works with `#` as the index. `json_insert(some_array, '$[#]', 'new item')` as of SQLite 3.31.0.

Answer (score 5):

A new notation was introduced in version [3.31.0](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_31_0.html) to directly support this functionality:

```sql
select json_insert('[1,2,3]', '$[#]', 4) -- → '[1, 2, 3, 4]'
```

Answer (score 2):

There's apparently no function or easy way to do it, but we can get there by:

- Breaking up each array value into a row with `json_each`
- Adding rows for the values we want to add with `UNION ALL`
- Grouping them with a sub-query and `GROUP BY`
- Packing them back together with `json_group_array`

For example if you have a `Messages` table with PRIMARY KEY `id` and a JSON array in `account`, you can add an element to the account array in all rows with:

```
SELECT id, json_group_array(value) FROM (
    SELECT Messages.id, json_each.value
    FROM Messages, json_each(Messages.account)
    UNION ALL SELECT Messages.id, 'new_account' FROM Messages
) GROUP BY id;
```

Which we need to wrap once more to put in a `UPDATE` as SQLite does not support `UPDATE` + `JOIN`. This will add the new account to all rows:

```
UPDATE Messages SET account = (SELECT account FROM (
    SELECT id, json_group_array(value) as account FROM (
        SELECT Messages.id, json_each.value
        FROM Messages, json_each(Messages.account)
        UNION ALL SELECT Messages.id, 'new_account' FROM Messages
    ) GROUP BY id
) WHERE id = Messages.id);
```

We can simplify this if you want to update only one row like this:

```
UPDATE Messages SET account = (
    SELECT json_group_array(value) FROM (
        SELECT json_each.value
        FROM Messages, json_each(Messages.account)
        WHERE Messages.id = 123456789
        UNION ALL SELECT 'new_account'
    ) GROUP BY ''
) WHERE id = 123456789;
```